# Bootstrap dropdown menu a:hover not full li:hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggle, dropdown

What is the best way to toggle display of my second level dropdown menu when hovering over "a"...not when hovering over the full "li"?

I use bootstrap and fiddle is : http://jsfiddle.net/2Smgv/3100/

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container-fluid">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">2-level Dropdown <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form action="" class="navbar-search pull-left">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search-query span2">
          </form>
          <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="#" href="#">Menu</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well sorry but i don't think your task will be solved as there is no li. actually its a tag with padding so you are not hovering on li but you are hovering on a tag with padding..

Comment: @Leo the lion - I'm not sure what you are trying to say here, there is an "li" AND it is a tag (multiple times with content). However, the default dropdown and hover functionality for bootstrap IS on the li and not the anchor tag.  The OP seems to want to change that.

Comment: @Leothelion - You are correct, I misunderstood the question.  Not for lack of reading but because it was not clear that "sub-menu" was referring to the class (.sub-menu).  I have edited the question for clarity.

Comment: @Leothelion - Also, your original comment is still confusing and may be for others who visit this question.  Are you trying to say that if the user's change were made that he would no longer be hovering over the li and thus not be able to navigate through the sub-menu?  Clearly there is an li and it is used in Bootstrap for hover.  If possible, please clarify to clear up confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand your question originally, and have updated my "answer" as such:

It is not possible to complete the modification you are requesting because the hover would be broken.  The display of and ability to mouse over sublist items functions because those items are within the parent list.  If you change the hover to the anchor tag, once you attempt to use the links within the subnav you will be outside of the anchor tag and thus removing the hover effect.

If you look at your markup, the

"2-level Dropdown" also contains the  and the  with class .sub-menu. Thus hovering over the sub-menu  is also over the parent

(2-level Dropdown).

However, the  containing "2-level Dropdown" ends with that text and the moving your cursor over the sibling sub-menu  means you are no longer hovering over the .

I hope this explains why it is not possible and allows you to gain an understanding of the reasons why.

Comment: well i think you did not read the question. Read Back "my sub-menu only when a is hover... not when the full li is hover " means op wants to show sub menu only when mouse in on a but not on li and this is not possible because li is not with width but a with padding. read with ease and you will see..thanx

Comment: And plz delete this answer as in your example user won't be able to go on sub menu as it will hide..check back what you did and please before posting as answer first test then  come or else it will mislead to other user..thanx

Comment: WHAT? I have no idea what you are trying to say.  You seem to be upset and awfully vengeful about someone trying to understand the question and help the OP.  I THOUGHT that was the purpose of this sight, not to give pompous responses and judgmental comments.  This entire interaction has been disappointing.  Have a good one!